# AngularJs Animation: Elements below the animated element are moving abruptly

Tags: angularjs, animation, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am beginning **angular animations**. I had successfully created an animation to an element to vanish upon a checkbox, but the elements below are moving up abruptly. What should I do so that those elements also animate?

```
</head>
<body ng-app="ngAnimate">
  <div ng-init="checked = true">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checked" />
    Is visible
  </label>
  <div class="content-area sample-show-hide" ng-show="checked">
    Content...
  </div>
    <div class="content-area">
    This Content is Moving up abruptly upward after I select the check box 'Is visible'. How can I move this up slowly instead?
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

See the 
    [plunker here](https://plnkr.co/edit/YFkjITxrJnbkCymGy2Xk?p=preview).

I am using bootstrap, so is there any way bootstrap can help here?

Comment: Try with JQuery. call the JQuery event on clicking the check box